# How to draw a filled polygon, no matter the order of the points?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a list of coordinates to make a polygon, but I can’t predict the order of the point ahead of time. I need it to fill all the space between these points, but I don’t understand how without knowing the order.

This is the code I have:
all_centre - is list of points

```
image2 = cv2.drawContours(image2, [all_centre], -1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
```

This is the image I'm getting:

[image: incorrect image]

I need it to be filled in like the blue squiggles here:

[image: incorrect image with hand-drawn fill to illustrate desired output]

Comment: Anna, your question is not quite complete as it is - if you could edit the code to be a complete example (e.g. give us the *actual* list of points) it would make your question much better. I've edited the formatting and wording to make it cleaner but it still needs some help from you.

Comment: try `fillConvexPoly`. or get `contourArea()` and if that's negative, reverse the list of points and draw that then

Comment: thank you all for responding! the question is closed, the solution is found (in the answer)

Comment: I think what you may be asking is for the convexHull(). Check that out.

Answer (score 3):

You can find convex hull with `cv2.convexHull` and draw it with `cv2.fillConvexPoly`.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.ones((500, 500, 3), np.uint8) * 255
coordinates = np.array([[60, 150], [80, 90], [140, 175], [160, 80], [200, 140]], int) * 2

# cv2.drawContours(image, [coordinates], -1, color=(255, 0, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
for pt in coordinates:
    cv2.circle(image, pt, 5, color=(255, 0, 0))

hull = cv2.convexHull(coordinates)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(image, hull, (255, 0, 255))
```

Comment: thank you so much!
I tried the graham algorithm and it worked! I think that the cv2.convexHull works on the same principle